# Php- Searching is not working if I set date without Zero?

Tags: php, mysql

I've html form where date from and date to field exits. So If select a date for example : 06/09/2014 It's showing result perfectly. But if I manually put a date e.g: 6/9/2014 then it's not showing any result. Strange ! Why It's showing the results ??

```
if(!empty($ad_datefrom) && empty($ad_dateto)){    
    $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date2 BETWEEN '$ad_datefrom' AND '$date'";    
}
```

**Note :** Column type is char(10) which storing date (m/d/y)

what I'm running to shift created_date column value to another created_date2 column :

```
<?php  
$q=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT cdid, created_date FROM contact_details ORDER BY cdid DESC");
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    $c=$r['created_date'];
    $cdid=$r['cdid'];   
    $c =  substr($c, 0, 10);

    $e=explode("/", $c);
    $e[0]; //date
    $e[1]; //month
    $e[2]; //year

    $c= $e[1]."-".$e[0]."-".$e[2]."<br/>";

    $u=mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE contact_details SET created_date2 = '$c' WHERE cdid = '$cdid'");
}

?>
```

Comment: If they are **strings** how this supposed to work? Mysql is not an AI that knows what exactly you want when you store your data in an **inappropriate** data types. Btw, your current data is completely broken, you cannot store `m/d/Y` in `char(10)` and compare by ranges.

Comment: @zerkms So it's should be `date` type, right ? But the value is storing something like that : 11/02/2014, 1/03/2014, 4/04/2014,

Comment: it should be `date`, right. Then when you want some formatting - you perform formatting. Don't confuse how data is stored and how it's represented. "But the value is storing something like that" --- nope

Comment: ok, I'm changing the date type. Let's see what happened.

Comment: @zerkms. There are 2 columns - `created_date` and `created_date2`. First column date type is `char(10) and it's storing d/m/y h:i` value and NOW second column data type is `date` and it's changed all date value to `0000-00-00`. So I run a query to shift all data from column one to column two but still Its showing `0000-00-00`.

Comment: "So I run a query to shift all data from column one to column two " --- and now we need to guess what query you've implemented?

Comment: `$c= $e[1]."-".$e[0]."-".$e[2]."<br/>";` --- so you put `<br/>` to `$c` and then mysql should treat it as a valid date? I hardly doubt `2014-11-24<br/>` is a valid date. Btw, you don't need to fetch row by row but might use `STR_TO_DATE` and perform all of those in one `UPDATE`

Comment: @zerkms OOPS! Now I run this line `$c= $e[1]."-".$e[0]."-".$e[2];` still column is empty.

Comment: @zerkms Ya It's inserted data successfully. But In html form Date pickup format is `m/d/y`. So then, my sql query will be wrong ?

Comment: again - don't confuse formats with data representation. If you want to compare your dates - format it to `YYYY-MM-DD` before comparison.

Comment: what is your format of `created_date` and `created_date2`

Comment: if format of `created_date` is `d/m/y h:i` then use this `$c=explode(" ",$c); $e=explode("/",$c[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$q=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT cdid, created_date FROM contact_details ORDER BY cdid DESC");
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    $cdid=$r['cdid'];   
    $c =explode(" ",$r['created_date']);

    $e=explode("/", $c[0]);
    $e[0]= str_pad($e[0],2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT); //date
    $e[1]=str_pad($e[1],2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT); //month
    $e[2]; //year

    $c= $e[2]."-".$e[1]."-".$e[0];
    //or use this
    // $c=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($r['created_date']));

    $u=mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE contact_details SET created_date2 = '$c' WHERE cdid = '$cdid'");
}
```

Comment: Now `created_date2` column data type is `date` format and the value is look like this : `2014-02-05` BUT In my form when I pick up a date, It's format is m/d/y. So according to my current `sql` query how do I search data using this 2 date format ??

Comment: u can use ` $c=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($r['created_date']));`  this code can convert from any string format of date to this `2014-02-05` format

Comment: for search query u can use `"AND STR_TO_DATE(cd.created_date2, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$ad_datefrom', '%Y-%m-%d')  AND STR_TO_DATE('$date'", '%Y-%m-%d');`